# How to create a subset of a oracle cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table which has these two columns, CreateDate and FlagId, among others. The FlagID is an integer column. I have to first extract all the rows with FlagID in (3000, 3001, 3002). I will do the select statement where FlagID in (3000, 3001, 3002) order by CreateDate, FlagID desc. Now I will have many sets of these three rows. I have to select the latest set of value. However, it may not always be set of three. It can be (3001, 3002), (3000, 3001, 3002) and so on. In this case I have to select the first two rows omitting subsequent sets. If the top rows have all three flags then I have to retrieve three rows. I have created an oracle cursor and got all rows selected by these values order by CreateDate . But I am not sure how to pick top set of rows by creating a subset from the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all rows newer than the penultimate date for the FlagId 3000.

Oracle:

```
SELECT CreateDate, FlagId
  FROM tab
 WHERE FlagId in (3000, 3001, 3002) and
 CreateDate > (SELECT MIN (CreateDate)
                       FROM (SELECT CreateDate
                               FROM (  SELECT CreateDate
                                         FROM tab
                                        WHERE FlagId = 3000
                                     ORDER BY CreateDate DESC)
                              WHERE ROWNUM < 3));
```

MySql:

```
select CreateDate, FlagId from t1
where FlagId in (3000, 3001, 3002) and
CreateDate >
(select min(CreateDate) from (
select CreateDate from t1
where FlagId = 3000
order by CreateDate desc
limit 2) sub);
```

Comment: If each set will have a single date then your solution will be really very elegant. However they will have different dates.

Comment: So you need the latest of each of the three values? How can they be a set if they don't share the same date?

Comment: It is a little more complex. First I have to get the latest 3000, and then any 3001 0r 3002 before another 3000 is encountered, order by date.

Comment: I have given it another try. Hope that will help you.

Comment: I am getting missing right parenthesis error between desc and limit 2

Comment: My bad, sorry. I thought is was MySql. I added an Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used hierarchical query to do this. First part enumerates data in order: `createdate desc, flagid`.
Second part takes first three rows in that order. Essence is in connect by clause: `prior fid < fid and rn = prior rn + 1`.

```
with enum as (
  select createdate cd, flagid fid, row_number() 
        over (order by createdate desc, flagid) rn
    from t where flagid in (3000, 3001, 3002) ) 
select cd, fid from enum where rn <= 3
  connect by prior fid < fid and rn = prior rn + 1
  start with rn = 1
```

Sample input and output:

```
CREATEDATE           FLAGID           CD                   FID
-------------------  ------           -------------------  ----
2015-03-24 11:48:29    3000           2015-03-25 12:24:52  3000
2015-03-24 11:48:29    3001           2015-03-25 11:49:13  3001
2015-03-24 11:48:29    3002           2015-03-25 11:49:13  3002
2015-03-25 11:48:45    3000
2015-03-25 11:48:45    3001
2015-03-25 11:49:13    3001
2015-03-25 11:49:13    3002
2015-03-25 12:24:52    3000
```